# pysvn: valid url triggers an error

Tags: python, url, pysvn

here is a sample code:

```
import pysvn
svnClient = pysvn.Client()
entry = svnClient.info('C:\\MyLibrary\\')
entry.url
headrev = svnClient.info(entry.url).revision.number
```

The last line triggers an error. entry.url appears to be correct: its value is

```
u'file:///G:/MyRepository/branches/branch_3.0'
```

Running the last line results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   pysvn._pysvn_2_7.ClientError: 'file:\G:\MyRepository\branches' is not a working copy 'C:\Python27\file:\G:\MyRepository\branches' does not exist
```

I am using Python 2.7 (as it is evident from the error message :-) on Windows.

Must be something trivial, but I do not know how to make it work.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the `Client.info` method doesn't expect a URL, just a filename (like you gave it in your earlier call). Does it work if you replace `svnClient.info(entry.url)` with just `entry`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it does not work: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: PyCXX: Error creating object of type class Py::String from <PysvnEntr
y u'.'>

Comment: I don't know enough about Subversion or pysvn to give specific guidance, but the general error is that you have a URL, `file:///G:/MyRepository/branches/branch_3.0` and you're giving it to a function that expects a local path. While a `file://` URL is actually local, you'll need to convert it to a path explicitly (by chopping off the protocol and probably by swapping the direction of the slashes) if you want to use it as a path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using string methods to filter the file:///C:/ from your entry.url and write it relative to your Python installation directory.

Comment: Cannot do it because the repository and python folder installation are on 2 different drives (have not mentioned it when asking the question because I thought it would be unnecessary detail). Anyway, having './../../../G:/MyRepository/branches' does not solve the problem; even if add an extra ../, C: persists, i.e. I get 'C:\G:\MyRepository\branches' in the error message

Comment: It looks like Client.info wants a local filename and gets confused when the file is on another drive. I'll look into it a bit more and tell you if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble you're having is that you have a URL, `file:///G:/MyRepository/branches/branch_3.0`, which you're passing to a function `pysvn.Client.info` which expects a local path, rather than a URL. When the function tries to treat the URL as a filename, it ends up looking in its current working directory (because the URL doesn't start with a drive letter or "/" character indicating an absolute path). Unsurprisingly it fails to find anything at `C:\Python27\file:\G:\MyRepository\branches`.

To fix this, you need to convert your URL into a legal file name. First, you need to chop off the protocol of the URL (that is, `file://`. Then you need to make sure the "path" part of the URL is legal for your operating system. Here's some code that will do that for you:

```
import pysvn
import urllib # note, the url2pathname function is in urllib.request in Python 3

svnClient = pysvn.Client()
entry = svnClient.info('C:\\MyLibrary\\')

url = entry.url
assert(url.startswith("file://")     # basic error checking
pathPart = url[7:]                   # chop off "file://" prefix
path = urllib.url2pathname(pathPart) # convert path to something OS appropriate

headrev = svnClient.info(path).revision.number
```

Note that this somewhat fragile. If you get something other than a `file://` URL back from your first call to the `info` method it will raise an `AssertionError`, which may not be what you want. I'm afraid I don't know enough about Subversion to know what you're trying to accomplish, or if there's a better way to do it. For instance, it might be worth looking at the `pysvn.Client.info2` method which seems to accept URLs for some kinds of requests.